# SSH Connections To Server (Using Keys)

Tags: linux, ssh

I have 2 servers that connect to each other for syncing and backups etc.

I do not know what has happened but for whatever reason DEV1A (Server Name) cannot connect to BS1.

When I am trying to connect the server through ssh I gets this error:

```
login as: root
root@dev1a password:
Last login: Thu Nov 20 09:35:35 2014 from dev1a
[root@dev1a ~]# ssh bs1.****
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
[root@dev1a ~]#
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I can connect to BS1 from any other location. It's driving me mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can connect from other locations to BS1, look in the logs of the `sshd` server on BS1.

If you see nothing of interest, start another `sshd` in debug mode on another port

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d -e -p 1234
```

and then connect to it on that port from DEV1A

```
ssh -p 1234 bs1.****
```

You should see the exact reason why the connection is rejected from the logs shown at the console on BS1.

Note that when a firewall, or iptables/fail2ban, prevent access to a server, you should not even see a message originating from `sshd` such as the one you get `ssh_exchange_identification:  Connection closed by remote host`

Answer (score 0):

Try following to connect to one server from another one.

`ssh -p <ssh port number of remote server>  <ip/domain of remote server>`

Comment: Have tried that, still get 
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check with debug option: 
`ssh -v ...`

Without the detail info it's really hard to help you with this type of error.

My bet is on the firewall that accidentally blocked your connect to server by your current ssh client.

Comment: I have disabled the firewall to see if it was that, and the same is happening. When running with debug, I get this

debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: I see the debug is whining about your key. If you're using key authenticate method for ssh login, use option -i #path to the key (id_rsa)#, since too many failed keys can cause disconnection to the current request. Otherwises, you can append the name of user to login: ssh -v root@bs1.***** to use password login.

Answer (score 0):

Got a firewall running?
Got fail2ban or denyhosts script running?

The sudden closed by indicates that your request is being routed to the trash on the other end. So you or someone else have tried this too many times with a wrong password.

So check BS1 and if something of that sort is running and if the IP from the other server is listed.

Comment: Checked both, disabled both and it still does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Well if you have "denyhosts" running, disableingit will not solve the problem as the IP is entered in a static file. Look in the /etc/hosts.deny file for the IP Adress. IT will be there. If that is your problem, check the documentation for the denyhosts script to see how you can avoid this in the future. There is a sort of "whitelist" you can add.

Comment: Have tried that also. Still no joy :( Might be time to wipe it.

Comment: Ok, then some facts are missing. check the logs on BS1 when you try and connect ... WHAT DO YOU SEE ... ? AS @damienfrancois already asked for. From what you describe there must be something appearingin the logs. We need to know what.